# JS bound function accesses window anyways

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to bind variable `c` to function `fn` but when the code is run `fn` still sees `this` as `window`. To me it seems like it would print each color twice in a row. Am I naive in thinking so? Any explanation as to why this may be happening? I am running in Chrome Canary and Firefox.

**Caution when running this code as it prints out the entire window object 3 times**

```js
const fn = () => {
  console.log(this);
}

[`red`, `orange`, `yellow`]
  .forEach(c => {
    console.log(c);
    fn.bind(c)();
  });
```

Comment: Arrow functions don't bind `this`. Use a regular function.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thank you. I was not aware that this was the case. You should post that as an answer because it completely solves the problem.